# Options validation in startup or class

Tags: c#, validation

In C# (ASP.NET Core), I often use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options):

```cs
public class FooConfig
{
    [Required]
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    private readonly FooConfig _config;

    public Foo(IOptions<FooConfig> options)
    {
        _config = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Use _config.MyString here, e.g.:
        Console.WriteLine("MyString starts with: " + _config.MyString[0]);
    }
}
```

When I use the config values, can I assume that the attributes have been validated? E. g., can I assume that `MyString` is not empty? Or is it better to add additional checks like this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_config.MyString))
    {
        throw [...];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("MyString starts with: " + _config.MyString[0]);
}
```

Usually, I add the validation when binding the options in application startup. However, the `Foo` class knows nothing about the startup, so it seems wrong to make validation assumptions in `Foo`.

```cs
services.AddOptions<FooConfig>()
    .Bind(Configuration.GetSection("Foo"))
    .ValidateDataAnnotations();
```

Comment: This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#options-validation

Comment: I read that section. Does this mean that it is correct that `Foo` should directly access `_config.MyString[0]` without checking for `null` or non-empty? To me it seems counter-intuitive that `Foo` can make such assumptions, since the validation is enabled / disabled at a totally different place (startup).

Comment: It seems like you philosophically worried  about whether something should do something else or not. If it makes you happy, check yourself and dont use options validation

Comment: That makes sense for code that is used by me. But what if Foo / FooConfig is part of a library that is used by many different applications? Some of them may have validation enabled, others have not. Do users expect, that a class validates its own options?

Comment: @pschill Nothing in software is predictable, always be defensive.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo` can make whatever assumptions you are comfortable with it making - it's *your* code. As Ermiya commented, "always be defensive," and Options classes can be defensively written in multiple ways, such as the aforementioned attribute validation or `IValidateOptions` approach, the options class providing reasonable default values, providing a readily accessible `IsValid` method or equivalent, or encouraging DI registration through a carefully managed extension method.

Either the options class is your own, in which case you can build as much of this into the class as you determine it requires and therefore skip checking things piecemeal downstream, or the options class is provided by an external source outside of your control. In that case, like any third-party code, you should trust nothing: if you are injecting someone else's options classes, then you should take control of validating it meets *your* code's expectations, either through checking important properties before consuming them or even re-implementing or extending the options class with some sort of wrapper so that you know you're getting exactly what you expect.